# Codemagic with Azure Dev Ops

Tags: flutter, dart, google-play, codemagic

I am trying to publish my flutter app to Google Play with codemagic. I am unable to get codemagic access to our Azure Dev Ops repo. It says not authorized I must be     doing something incorrectly.

Im getting Authentication failed .

Answer (score 3):

have you connected the repo by clicking "Add app from custom source"? https://docs.codemagic.io/getting-started/adding-apps-from-custom-sources/